# Nested form working in new but not showing up in edit Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a invoice application where i have the @invoice form and inside it i have nested forms for customers, products, and company information. The products form is working fine in all views but the customer form isn't. When i fill in the customer information and create a new invoice it works. But when i try to edit that invoice the entire form is gone.

**invoice/_form**

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
<% if @invoice.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@invoice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invoice from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :customer do |customer| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= customer.label 'Bedrijfsnaam ontvanger' %><br/>
    <%= customer.text_field :company_name, placeholder: 'bedrijfsnaam', class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= customer.label 'Adres ontvanger' %><br>
    <%= customer.text_field :address_line_1, placeholder: 'adres ontvanger', class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= customer.label 'Postcode & stad' %><br>
    <%= customer.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: '1234AB Rotterdam', class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

**Invoices_controller.rb**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end

  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @invoice.products.build
    @invoice.build_customer
  end

  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal,
                                      :subtotal, :total, :footer, customers_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :address_line_1, :zip_code, :_destroy],
                                      companies_attributes: [:id, :btw_number, :iban_number, :kvk_number, :company_name, :_destroy],
                                      products_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :description, :unitprice, :btw, :total])
    end
end
```

**Invoice.rb - (model)**

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :company
  has_one :customer
  has_many :products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates :number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal, :subtotal, :total, presence: true

end
```

Comment: What do you new and edit views look like? What you labelled "invoice_form" looks like a partial so we need to see what is causing the partial.

Comment: The new and edit views are just rendering the '_form' partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the invoices controller try changing `customers_attributes` to `customer_attributes` in your strong params:

```
customer_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :address_line_1, :zip_code, :_destroy]
```

I suspect this is an issue where your customer nested attributes are not being properly saved, so when you go to the edit view that part of the form isn't being rendered because there isn't any customer saved for your invoice

Comment: Oh wow, i totally overlooked on that one.. thanks man it's working now!